# Time stamp from string issue?

Tags: swift, locale, unix-timestamp

I have two string , date and time . date string has a date in format "MM-dd-yyyy" and time in format "hh:mm a" , I want to create a 10 digit timestamp from the same . I did the following but I am getting issue with this. Any help is appreciated.

```
let idate = (userInstance.userData?.Date!)! + "T" + (userInstance.userData?.Time!)!  + "+0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: idate)!
print(date)

let timestamp = Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970)
print(timestamp)
```

Comment: What does "I am getting issue with this" mean?

Comment: its crashing bcoz idate cannot be converted

Comment: Can you please post the crash log?

Comment: the problem I this is that I have AM and PM in my date. but I tried giving yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm a:ssZ

Comment: You need to show actual input, actual desired output, and crash log.

Comment: Unrelated but code such as `(userInstance.userData?.Date!)!` is a poor way to work with optionals. Please give serious consideration to doing this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force a date containing AM/PM time to ISO 8601. ISO 8601 dates are always represented in 24-hour mode.
Besides your order of year, month and day is not ISO 8601 compliant.

Specify the appropriate date format `MM-dd-yyyyhh:mm aZ`

```
let datePart = "09-18-2018"
let timePart = "4:22 pm"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyyhh:mm aZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: datePart + timePart + "+0000")!
let timestamp = Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970)
print(timestamp)
```

Comment: This answer assumes you want the date and time to be treated at a UTC timestamp. The OP doesn't clarify but it is quite possible it is a local timestamp. If that is the case, do not add the `Z` to the format and don't append the `+0000` to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are crashing here:

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: idate)!
```

That's because you are claiming that `idate` is a string in this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

But it isn't. When you convert from a string to a date, your format string must *exactly* match the format of the string.

*Then* you can supply a different format and convert the date to a new string.